# How to show icon (onclick) and remove after 3 seconds?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a dropdown item and onclick I want it to show an icon, then remove it after 3 seconds. ngHide seems not to be working.

I have already tried setTimeout, but it doesn't work.

```
<a class="dropdown-item" (click)="onReportClick()">Report
    <i class="icon ion-md-checkmark listing-dropdown-icon" ngHide="reportIcon"></i>
</a>
```

```
export class CardComponent implements OnInit {
  appname = '';

  onReportClick() {

  }

  ngOnInit() { }

  constructor() { }
}
```

I expect the icon to appear `(onclick)="onReportClick()"` then disappear after 3 seconds.

Comment: Note: `ngHide` is not working properly, because that does not exist in Angular 2+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<i class="icon ion-md-checkmark listing-dropdown-icon" [hidden]="reportIcon"></i>

<!---->

export class CardComponent implements OnInit {
  appname = '';
  reportIcon = true;

  onReportClick() {
    this.reportIcon = false;
    setTimeout(() => { this.reportIcon = true }, 3000)
  }

  ngOnInit() { }

  constructor() { }
}
```